# Is it save to power off a PC without shutting down?

Tags: hard-drive, transaction

Is all software nowadays writing data transnational to disk?
So that if it is interrupted during writing there won't be a corrupt file?

Let's say I have a PC running Windows or Debian.
And some well known programs like Firefox and LibreOffice.

Is it safe to power off the PC without shutting down (this happens to me if there is a blackout)?
Or might this result in corrupt files?

Comment: Having a blackout 1-2/yr general isn't a problem, but there is still a chance it will be corrupted.  If you have frequent power issues get a UPS.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Transactions hinder performance significantly, therefore it's unlikely that everything will be transactional anytime soon.

Comment: Is think that's not true. For example if you only have a configuration file the overhead is very small (you don't need a database).

Comment: Unless there's another actor that tries to read or write this file simultaneously. It's also a cherry-picked example. Some files are small, but some are not. Even databases, which in majority are transactional to guarantee data integrity, don't guarantee full transaction isolation by default because performance impact may not be worth it (see [isolation levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_levels) - most DBMSes use _read commited_)